# Htaccess redirect without addressbar change

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've been trying to create a redirect from http://www.example.com/photos/may/album/ to http://www.example.com/photos/gallery?id=21. I want to keep the address the same as original and the files in the album must also be reachable.

I already find this and it's almost working, but this changes the url in the addressbar:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/photos/may/album/$ /photos/gallery?id=21
</IfModule>
```

Can someone point me to the right way?

Comment: Are you saying that you're typing in `http://www.example.com/photos/may/album/` in the address bar and then it's redirecting you to `http://www.example.com/photos/gallery?id=21` (as in, the address bar changes)?

Comment: That is how it now works. It's a possible solution, but it's better that the original link 'http://www.example.com/photos/may/album/' stays in the address bar